# How can I change a method assigned on an event?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am getting all events, with a certain attribute, and I want to modify these events adding a call to another method.

```
var type = GetType();
var events = type.GetEvents().Where(e => e.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExecuteAttribute), false).Length > 0);

foreach (var e in events)
{
    var fi = type.GetField(e.Name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField);
    var d = (Delegate)fi.GetValue(this);
    var methods = d.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (var m in methods)
    {
        var args = e.EventHandlerType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, "p")).ToArray();
        var body = m.Method.GetMethodBody();

        /**

        TODO:

        Create a new method with the body of the previous
        and add a call to another method

        Remove current method
        Add the new created method

        **/
    }
}
```

What I want is basically what is commented above. "Modify" the subscribed methods of the event. I guess I can't subscribe to it, because I need to pass the parameters the method is passing to the big handler (the new method).

One more example based [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441672/how-can-i-dynamically-inject-code-into-event-handlers-in-delphi). I want to convert this:

```
var e += (x) =>
{
    var y = x;
};
```

To something like this:

```
var e += (x) =>
{
    var y = x;

    BigHandler(x); // injected code
};
```

Or this:

```
var e += (x) => // new method
{
    previousE(x); // previous method

    BigHandler(x); // additional code
}
```

How can I do it?

---

The bigger goal:

I need to "detect" when an event is fired and call a method. I also need to send the parameters it is using.

So I can make something like:

```
public delegate void OnPostSaved(Post p);
[Execute]
public event OnPostSaved PostSaved;

public void Save()
{
    /* save stuff */
    // assume that there is already an event subscribed
    PostSaved(post);
}
```

Then on my handler method I can check if an event from `XYZ` was fired, check which event was fired, retrieve the parameter and do something. For example:

```
public void BigHandler(string eventName, params object[] p)
{
    if (eventName == "PostSaved")
    {
        var post = p[0] as Post;
        MessageBoard.Save("User posted on the blog: " + post.Content);
    }
}
```

I know it can be achieved using `PostSharp`, but I can't use it. I need another solution.

---

**Related**

- [C# Reflection, changing a method's body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645410/c-reflection-changing-a-methods-body)
- [How can I dynamically inject code into event handlers in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441672/how-can-i-dynamically-inject-code-into-event-handlers-in-delphi)

---

**Update 2010-09-27** I couldn't find a solution neither more info on it, I still need help. Added +150 bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just *adding* a call, it's really easy - you don't need to fetch all the subscribed delegates or anything like that; just subscribe with reflection:

```
var type = GetType();
// Note the small change here to make the filter slightly simpler
var events = type.GetEvents()
                 .Where(e => e.IsDefined(typeof(ExecuteAttribute), false));

foreach (var e in events)
{
    // "handler" is the event handler you want to add
    e.AddEventHandler(this, handler);
}
```

Now, I've made an assumption about what you want to do - namely call your method *once* each time the event is raised. That's not the same as calling your method *once every time an event handler is called* which is what your original code would have done. That's *much* harder... but do you really need it?

(If you could give more information about the bigger goal here, it would really help.)

Note that the code I've provided here should work *regardless* of how the event is implemented - it doesn't rely on it being a field-like event.

EDIT: Okay, here's a complete example showing how you can add a plain `EventHandler` delegate to any event which matches the normal eventing pattern:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs {}

delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs e);

class Publisher
{
    public event EventHandler PlainEvent;
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> GenericEvent;
    public event CustomEventHandler CustomEvent;

    public void RaiseEvents()
    {
        PlainEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        GenericEvent(this, new CustomEventArgs());
        CustomEvent(this, new CustomEventArgs());
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Publisher p = new Publisher();

        Type type = typeof(Publisher);

        foreach (EventInfo eventInfo in type.GetEvents())
        {
            string name = eventInfo.Name;
            EventHandler handler = (s, args) => ReportEvent(name, s, args);
            // Make a delegate of exactly the right type
            Delegate realHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                 eventInfo.EventHandlerType, handler.Target, handler.Method);
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(p, realHandler);
        }

        p.RaiseEvents();
    }

    static void ReportEvent(string name, object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event {0} name raised with args type {1}",
                          name, args.GetType());
    }
}
```

Note how we have to construct the exact type of delegate required - but we know we can do that from a *compatible* method, so long as everything follows the normal event pattern.

Comment: I've added the "bigger goal". Your current answer is close, sorry that I forgot to mention that I need to get the parameters the method subscribing is passing. I've added more info...

Comment: @BrunoLM: That's just a matter of building the appropriate delegate, by the looks of it. I'm going out now, but I'll have a look in about an hour, if you haven't solved it by then. Lambda expressions may well be your friend.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I still don't get it... How can I get the object that the event is using? The only way I can think of is to modify the same method. I need something like `BigHandler(eventName, params_from_the_event.ToArray<object>()`

Comment: @BrunoLM: What do you mean by "the object that the event is using"? Do you mean the `(object sender, EventArgs e)` part (or whatever the signature of the event is)?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Whatever signature. I want to get all params and throw into an `object[]`

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I believe the signature is not a problem. The var `args` on my code return the signature of the method.

Comment: @BrunoLM: Do you actually have to cope with *any* kind of event, or just a specific set of them? It would be easy if everything followed the convention of `(object sender, T args)` where T is some type deriving from `EventArgs`, for example.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It would be better if it worked with any kind of event. But if there is a way to do it using `(object sender, T args)` it would be enough. I could change the events to match this signature...

Comment: @BrunoLM: Okay, that should be doable - especially if T derives from EventArgs, again as per the pattern.

Comment: @BrunoLM: I've created a test program which you can use to see what to do.

Comment: @BrunoLM: Glad we got there in the end :)