# Change what a method returns at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, methods, boolean, return

Is there any way to make this method return true under a certain condition during runtime? Quick note: All I want to know is if this is at all possible. Trust me, alternative ways of writing the method won't help.

```
public bool Example()
{
    return false;         
}

if(//Certain condition is satisfied)
{
    //Example method returns true instead
}
```

Comment: Why not replace `false` with the `Certain condition`?

Comment: Why `alternative ways of writing the method won't help`?

Comment: `All I want to know is if this is at all possible` - probably not in the way that you'd like. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645410/c-sharp-reflection-changing-a-methods-body

Comment: @user3277234: "Trust me, alternative ways of writing the method won't help." Considering the top answer of your question, apparently the community doesn't trust you.  I suggest you explain why alternative ways of writing the method won't help.  Many SO users are too afraid of the X-Y problem to be willing to provide help with weird things until they know why those weird things are necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I occasionally have to do this. Here's what I do:

- Attach a CLR profiler to the process before it starts.
- Set the profiler to be called back when `Example` is jitted.
- Do IL injection to replace its contents with the code of my choice.

Now I control whether the method returns true or false.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just read in some input from a console/UI/file to determine what to do?

Comment: @Servy: Almost anything would be easier. Apparently the condition of the problem is "without modifying the method". In my case the method which I wish to control whether it returns true or false is deep inside the implementation of MSBUILD, and I cannot change the inputs to MSBUILD, but I need to change its behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
public bool Example()
{
    if(//Certain condition is satisfied)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;         
}
```

> Trust me, alternative ways of writing the method won't help.

I beg to differ. Perhaps if you explain your actual problem, instead of your attempted solution, a more accurate answer can be given.

Comment: Just differ.  Begging is unbecoming.

Comment: @Dan-o can you explain that one? Non-native English speaker here. ;-)

Comment: It was a glib remark.  Commenting on your remark `I beg to differ`.  I was just pointing out that begging was not attractive.  You should just differ, and forget about the begging.  It was supposed to be humorous.. but as with most humor its not funny if it needs to be explained.

Comment: One can always replace this pattern with just `return conditionalExpression;`  There's no need for an `if` or multiple returns.

Comment: @Servy of course, I just moved the `if` into the method to illustrate its use as closely resembling the code in the question as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Example()
{
 return Certaincondition;         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your case, why don't you just create an interface and two implementations (an implementation that returns true and an implementation that returns false); and use the correct implementation based on your if-statement?

```
 public interface IMyInterface
 {
     public bool MyMethod();
 }

 public class Impl1 : IMyInterface
 {
     public bool MyMethod()
     {
          return true;
     }
 }

 public class Impl2 : IMyInterface
 {
     public bool MyMethod()
     {
          return false;
     }
 }

 // in your logic somewhere
 if(//Certain condition is satisfied)
 {
     new Impl1().MyMethod();
 } else 
 {
     new Impl2().MyMethod();
 }
```